# How can i run QJackCtl and the dafault divice audio at the same time?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

i want to use Guitarix, using QJackCtl and alsa, and play some music in background, like backing tracks to practice. I was using Ubuntu Studio and worked just fine, but now i've install Ubuntu 18.04 and i can't work it out. I alredy followed this [jack audio config](https://jackaudio.org/faq/linux_rt_config.html) and it didn't worked.

Comment: Ubuntu Studio spend a lot effort getting the configuration right, why not just add that on top of your 'new' Ubuntu 18.04 system?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UbuntuStudioInstaller

Comment: because i didn't know, that's why i'm asking.... thank you by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu Studio spend a lot effort getting the configuration right, why not just add that on top of your 'new' Ubuntu 18.04 system?

> Ubuntu Studio includes Ubuntu Studio Installer by default. For other
>   flavors, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-installer
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UbuntuStudioInstaller

To use, simply click on the icon for Ubuntu Studio Installer, or find it in your launcher/dash.

Once it is open, you will see a window like this:
[image]
Simply click on the packages you desire in the left-hand box (descriptions of those packages are in the right-hand box).

If you wish to add the [Ubuntu Studio Backports PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/BackportsPPA) to have the latest versions of certain packages as they become available, click "Add Backports PPA".

Comment: The PPA is recommended too, as Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **not** a LTS, but it's packages have extended support the moment you add the PPA, meaning they are supported until 2021-April (3 years which is standard flavor support)